# Basic racket syntax question

Tags: syntax, racket

I came across the following piece of syntax in Racket, could anyone tell me what it means? I tried Googling it to no avail.

```
symbol=?
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're using DrRacket, then hit <kbd>F1</kbd> to find [this documentation](http://pre.racket-lang.org/docs/html/reference/booleans.html?q=symbol=#%28def._%28%28lib._racket/bool..rkt%29._symbol~3d~3f%29%29):

> `(symbol=? symbol1 symbol2 symbol3 ...)`    procedure
>
> Returns `#t` if the symbols are the same, i.e., if their names are spelled the same.

Answer (score 7):

I think that the confusion here is that `symbol=?` looks like some syntax for some weird expression.  Racket follows Scheme and Lisp tradition where the syntax is pretty minimal: identifiers are very permissive, so this whole thing is just a name of a function.  (And see rm's answer for what the function actually does.)